# UTF-8 decode this.props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

fetching from a mongodb, and I would like to display the string in a readable format. The string is user created (a product description) and will usually include apostrophes. I would like to be able to decode the UTF-8 format into a readable string. eg.

`Susan's delicious grapefruits.` // instead of // `Susan&#x27;s delicious grapefruits.`

I considered something like this, but it just threw up errors:

```
decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(this.props.product.desc));
```

As I am passing the data as a prop to the component, what would be the best approach to this, in terms of code and lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling JSX using gulp, then the generated file is not UTF-8, so you need to safe file in Utf-8.

Also, did you added `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to your html file?

And here is useful link - https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Comment: I am not using gulp and I have the meta charset set to UTF-8 in the HTML file